# Apple Watch Remote Old iPhone

Tags: iphone, remote-control, apple-watch

My setup is as follows:

I have the Apple Watch on my wrist, and I have an old iPhone 4s with iOS 8.4 sitting on a docking station

Can I control the music playing through the iPhone through the Watch? - I can control the music playing on my mac & newer iPhone 6 but can't figure out, if possible, how to do it on the old one?

Comment: the newest one available 8.4

Answer (score 1):

You can't control music on the iPhone 4s because Apple made it so the iPhone 4s doesn't support the Apple Watch.